# Trying render html entities in my express ejs Application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

Here is the page I am trying to render

```
<% include ../partials/boilerplate %>



    <div class="triviaContainer">
        <h1>GAME TIME!!! </h1>
        <% var i =0; data.forEach(question =>{ i+=1 %>

    <div class="questionRow">
        <div> <%= question.question  %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="questionRow1">
        <div  clicked="" id="correctanswer<%=i %>" class="correctAnswer"  > A: <%= question.correct_answer %></div>

        <div clicked="" id="incorrectanswer<%=i %>" class="incorrectanswer<%=i %>" >B: <%= question.incorrect_answers[0].incorrect_answer %></div>
    </div>
    <div class="questionRow2">
        <div clicked="" id="secondincorrectanswer<%=i %>"  >C: <%= question.incorrect_answers[1].incorrect_answer %></div>
        <div clicked="" id="lastanswer<%=i %>" >D: <%= question.incorrect_answers[2].incorrect_answer %></div>
    </div>


     <%   }) %>
<form class="gameForm" method='POST' action='/trivia/score'>

    <input type="hidden" name="points" value="" id="points"/> 
    <input type="hidden" name="gameid" value="<%= data[0].game_id %>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="questions" value="<%= data[0].number_of_questions %>"/> 
    <input type="submit" value="GET RESULTS">
</form>
       </div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/triviaGameScript.js"></script>

<% include ../partials/end %>
```

I am rendering the questions in the question.question portion of the foreach function. If you look at this screen shot, the last question has a quote html entity. I have several questions that have these entities and would like to find an npm package to decode them.
[image: The last question next to the fedex is where the entity is]

Here is the controller where I am requiring html-entities npm package

```
const triviaModel = require('../models/trivia');
const authHelpers = require('../services/auth/auth-helpers')
const Entities = require('html-entities').XmlEntities;
const entities = new Entities();
const triviaapiController = {};

triviaapiController.index = (req, res) => {
console.log(req.body.game_id);
triviaModel.GetGame(req.body.game_id)
    .then(data =>{
          console.log(data);

          res.render('trivia/trivia-index', {
            data: data,
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({ err });
    });
}
```

the data portion in the trivia-index promise is where the questions and answers are stored.

here is the documentation for this particular package. `https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-entities` I am not specifically sure how to use it. Should I apply it in the ejs file, or to the data object that is getting passed in. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You code use the package like that:

```
triviaapiController.index = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.game_id)
  triviaModel.GetGame(req.body.game_id)
    .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      var decodedData = []
      for (var q of data) {
        var decodedQ = {
          question: entities.decode(q.question),
          correct_answer: q.correct_answer,
          incorrect_answers: q.incorrect_answers
        }
        decodedData.push(decodedQ)
      }

      res.render('trivia/trivia-index', {
        data: decodedData
      })
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      res.status(500).json({ err})
    })
}
```

Comment: Yeah man, that worked. I appreciate the help! I need to think outside the box! Still new to the programming game.